# ¿ querySelector es compatible con todos los selectores CSS3?

Tags: javascript, css3, sql

Me he informado que el metodo **querySelector** esta bien soportado, pues es compatible hasta con internet explorer 8, no obstante, me pregunto, en el tiempo en que fue creado no existia el css3 y sus selectores modernos como nth-child....¿si uso esos selectores en el **queryselector** seguirá siendo compatible este metodo con los navegadores mas viejos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`querySelector` acepta cualquier selector de css3, si hay alguna excepción, me da que todavía no me he topado con ella (Y lo he utilizado con `:not()`, `nth-child`, etc).

Si el navegador no es compatible con selectores de css3, me da que tampoco lo va a ser con javascript "moderno". Pero si tenemos que preocuparnos por navegadores que no se han actualizado en los últimos... ¿10 años? Creo que tendríamos que decir adiós a muchísimas funcionalidades.